# Stopping Dataflow stream job without deleting it's created PubSub subscription

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'd like to stop a Dataflow streaming job that reads from PubSub, but retain it's created subscription.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: What is current situation? Does your Dataflow job create a subscription in PubSub and when you stop it the subscription is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a PubSub source you can either provide a topic or a subscription. If you do not specify a subscription one will be created by Dataflow and managed for you. I don't think there's a way to keep the subscription created and managed by Dataflow alive after the pipeline.